# Is there a phrase such as "Anxious of"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, phrases

I want by the following sentence to express that **death causes anxiety for souls**:

> And why do souls become **anxious of** it?..

*It refers to death*

I have looked for the phrase, but it gets corrected each time for "anxious about". I think those two phrases are kind of opposites to each other because, here, souls are not concerned about death but afraid (anxious to be more precise) of it.

Also, I want to preserve the ***sentence structure*** as it is if possible.

So, is **anxious of** right to convey the intended meaning (in bold)?

Comment: If you're so anxious to preserve the _of_, you'd probably try and use _apprehensive_ instead. _Anxious_ does not usually collocate with _of_, afaik.

Comment: Your first sentence should be "death causes [**anxiety**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/anxiety)..." In the block quoted sentence, if you want to use "anxious" then you need "about", as the spell checker advises.

Comment: @MvLog _ "Apprehensive of" seems to be a great alternative. Thank you.

Comment: @WeatherVane _ Yes, it was an unintentional mistake. I would avoid using "about" as it doesn't quite convey what I want.

Comment: You would not say *concerned **of** either*. It's *concerned* ***about*** and *anxious* ***about***. Using *of* with either word is unidiomatic at best and ungrammatical at worst. If you insist on the specific phrase *anxious of*, then the answer here will be that it's wrong. You can change the word that comes before the preposition (such that *of* becomes okay), but only *about* works with anxious.

Comment: @JasonBassford _ Understood. Thank you. But **anxious about** wouldn't convey the meaning I intend, right?

Comment: @JasonBassford Your comment seems to be an actual answer to the question. Please move it to answers so I can vote on it.

Comment: @Valkor It's not apparent if it's not a satisfactory answer to the person asking the question.

Comment: @JasonBassford _ In [this thread](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/anxious-for-anxious-about-or-anxious-of.2144122/), the member named "boozer" explained the difference between **anxious of** and **anxious about** based on the presented sentence by the asker. They seemed according to their explanation that they convey opposite meanings.

Comment: @tasneemzh The distinction made in that post is erroneous because *anxious about the success of our team* can, itself, apply to all the meanings discussed. There is no need to use the (I believe) erroneous *anxious of* for one of the meanings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered in the comments:

> "You would not say *concerned **of*** either. It's *concerned about* and *anxious about*. Using *of* with either word is unidiomatic at best and ungrammatical at worst. If you insist on the specific phrase *anxious of*, then the answer here will be that it's wrong. You can change the word that comes before the preposition (such that *of* becomes okay), but only *about* works with anxious." – Jason Bassford